# How to use arm_acle C language extensions in android

Tags: c, android-ndk, arm, neon

There are lots of examples of using arm neon intrinsics for android, with the ndk even having an example. I've gotten that to work with no problem.

Arm also offer the ACLE (Arm C Language Extension), but I can find next to nothing by way of examples. The arm document itself merely suggests including the arm_acle.h header file, however I still get errors. Google has offered almost zero assistance :) Also searching the arm community boards has yielded little by way of results.

Do people not use the acle, and chose inline assembly instead?

When I inlcude the arm_acle.h and atttempt to use the __ssat() call, I have to further define a directive __ARM_FEATURE_CRC32, and when building I get the error" error: '__builtin_arm_qadd' was not declared in this scope"

The header doesn't seen to include any dependencies, and the documentation list no specific link dependencies.

Any advice?

Or am I overlooking something fundamental here?

**Additional Information:**
My target arch is armv7-a-neon and is correctly detected in the make file at build time.
I then further define "-mfloat-abi=softfp -mfpu=neon -march=armv7", but to no avail.
If I undo my additional debugging defines, I simply get " error: #error "ACLE intrinsics support not enabled." (Neon support and detection succeeds)
Searching my code base, the arm_acle.h header file is only present for the clang **host** tools, whereas arm_neon.h is is present for several prebuilts tool arm directories.

As I said, the arm_neon works detection works fine, and runs fine, it's the arm_acle component that doesn't work.
Searching the online repositories like http://androidxref.com seems to suggest only neon is supported?

Comment: What CPU/architecture version are you telling the compiler to target? I wouldn't be surprised if Android tools are still targeting ARMv5 as a baseline, in which case you're not going to get access to v6 instructions like `ssat` by default. Indeed, the fact that you're manually defining something which [should be predefined by a compiler based on the target CPU](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.dui0774b/chr1383660321827.html) is a bit of a giveaway that your options are probably wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ARM C Language Extensions are currently not fully supported in GCC (as of version 5.1). The Android NDK normally uses a version of GCC older than this, which also does not have full support for ACLE.

This page https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/ARM-C-Language-Extensions-_0028ACLE_0029.html gives some idea of the current level of implementation of ACLE for both ARM and AArch64 targets. As you'll see there, the only features of ACLE currently provided by GCC are the CRC32 intrinsics in `arm_acle.h` and the Neon Intrinsics you've already found in `arm_neon.h`.

Comment: That seem's to fit with what I've been seeing. Thank you for the details and answer!